# how to let xmlstarlet formatting do NOT collapse/shrink an empty tag?

Tags: xmlstarlet

original
`<someTag></someTag>`

but after running:
`xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl --indent-spaces 1`
it becomes
`<someTag/>`
but I need it to not shrink it and keep the original format
`<someTag></someTag>`

`fo --html` didn't help complaining about invalid tags (but will not complain w/o it)

The `ed -L` will also shrink it, and with `-P` (to keep whitespace) will not indent, and I need the indenting.

PS.: I found a lot of questions/answers but none related to xmlstarlet.

Comment: Why do you need the original format? `<someTag></someTag>` and `<someTag/>` are synonymous.

Comment: mainly to easy hand editing and keep the changes at a minimum during compare, and a few other reasons..

Comment: This isn't possible with xmlstarlet, you might be able to hack something up with sed, like in this similar question about CDATA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400259/can-xmlstarlet-preserve-cdata-during-copy

Comment: @npostavs very good! yup, running `sed` after, just to expand `<someTag/>` into `<someTag></someTag>`, will work perfectly, and I know how to implement it thx! feel free to answer as workaround if you prefer, considering `xmlstarlet` is unable (to the date) to lower it's high quality formatter (in a sense that, "why keep useless xml if it can be shrinked, if it will be the best result" independent of what the user needs xD).

Comment: xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl --nocdata does transform <someTag><![CDATA[]]</someTag> to <someTag></someTag> and not to <someTag/>...

Answer (score 1):

`xmlstarlet c14n xml-file` outputs [Canonical XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML) which is intended for comparing XML documents. Among other things, canonicalization converts empty elements to start-end tag pairs and forces lexicographic attribute order so beware that output may have more changes than you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The c14n encoding will...

- Add <![CDATA[textcontent]]> tags to text fields with spaces
- Not preserve comments unless the additional --with-comments or --exc-with-comments commands line parameters are used